# Swizzling colors in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to write a ffmpeg filter that takes two videos and blends them together such that Y (luma) of the first one becomes red channel out the output and Y of the second - the blue channel of the output (green just gets set to zero).
To put it another way, I want this: [v0][v1] r=v0.y:b=v1.y:g=0 [out]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your inputs are YUV and you want packed RGB, use

```
ffmpeg -i yr.mp4 -i yb.mp4 -filter_complex
       "[0][1]mergeplanes=0x001000:gbrp,lut=g=0,format=rgb24" -c:v png out.mov
```

In `0x001000`, the first pair `00` sets the first outplane (the g in `gbrp`) to be the first plane of the first input i.e. luma of yr.mp4. This is random, since g will be set to zero later on. Then `10`, which sets second outplane to first plane of second input i.e. luma of yb.mp4. Finally, the third plane is set to luma of first input. Then the lut filter resets the G plane to zero. A format filter is added to repack the pixels as the common `rgb24` format. The PNG codec is chosen so as to retain the RGB coding.